# How to delete item from list permanently

Tags: python, list

So I'm supposed to use the delete function to delete an item from a list using the index of the item. I'm quite new to python but I wanted to know if there is a way to have that element deleted in every function that the list exists in. For example, when I call a function that contains the list, I want the item to also be deleted in that list. I don't mind clarifying if this is too confusing.

Comment: " but I wanted to know if there is a way to have that element deleted in every function that the list exists in." Lists do not exist *in* functions, really. References to that list could, or to objets that reference that list. In any case, if you `del my_list[i]` (i'm presuming that's what you mean by "delete function") then that effect will be seen for **any** reference to that list. So your question isn't really clear. What problem exactly are you encountering

Answer (score 0):

Lists are `mutable` in python.
So when you delete an item from the list it is deleted from all references to that list. (so long as it is not a **copy** of a list).

To delete an item, use `pop()`.

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
x.pop(1)
```

returns this:

```
['a', 'c']
```

And the same is true with functions. An example is this code:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = x

def remove_from_list(my_list):
    my_list.pop(1)

remove_from_list(y)
print(y)
```

Also returns:

```
['a', 'c']
```